# Is it bad practice to only have one DbContext in EF Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have about ~250 dbsets in my DbContext, I'm wondering wether or not it would make a significant difference (in performance) if I would separate them (and possibly group them in lets say max 15 for example) or wether I should make a separate DbContext for each DbSet?

Kind regards

Comment: It's nothing wrong. As long as you dispose after every action, you will be fine.

Comment: @Asherguru It is not recommended to dispose the DbContext manually. Please check [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/359672/344707). Your DI is responsible for it as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#overview-of-dependency-injection-1)

Comment: what i mean is to dispose the interface and also inject dependency for interface and dbcontext. sorry for my unclear comment.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150383/should-efs-dbcontext-contains-all-tables).